# Are bundled re-exports in a library tree shaken?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Say I have a library with the following `index.js` file

```
import { a } from './a'
import { b } from './b'
import { c } from './c'
import { d } from './d'

export const myLibrary = {
    a, b, c, d
}

export default myLibrary
```

If a consumer using Webpack consumes the library and uses the following syntax:

```
import myLibrary from 'my-library'

myLibrary.a('Only include this function')
```

will `b()`, `c()`, `d()` be removed from the final bundle through tree shaking?

Answer (score 0):

```
export const myLibrary = {
    a, b, c, d
}

export default myLibrary
```

This is currently is not tree shakable, however tree shaking this syntax should be supported in webpack `5.x`.

```
import {a} from './a'
import {b} from './b'
import {c} from './c'

export { a, b, c }
```

The above syntax has limited tree shaking support in `4.x` and will be fully tree shakable in `5.x`. This syntax is currently tree shakable in `webpack@next`